# How do you recover an SVN repository?

Tags: svn

The computer containing a repository had a motherboard crash. We replaced the computer and the hard drive was intact so we have all of the SVN data.

How do you re-enable the repository and not lose the history, versioning, etc.?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any SVN-repository physically is just a part of ordinary FS-tree with files and folders, which contain **all data** in it.

If you know location of repositories on drive, you can copy repository(ies) to the new location as any other objects on HDD. You'll have to add|configure "access layer" for repos later, but it's another story